# Can't load the web page content using php5 domdocument

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing, domdocument

```
<?php
    class parsedictionary {
        public function _process() {
            $webpage="http://www.oppapers.com/essays/Computerized-World/160871?read_essay";
            $doc=new DOMDocument();
            $doc->loadHTML($webpage);
            echo $doc;
        }
    }
    $obj=new parsedictionary();
    $obj->_process();
?>
```

I can't get the content of that page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <p>http://www.oppapers.com/essays/Computerized-World/160871?read_essay</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But i need to get the content of that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DOMDocument` class is obviously not a string; you can iterate it, perform operations on it, but it can't just be echoed. Check the documentation to see what you can do with it: http://www.php.net/domdocument

To get the page contents, you can either use `file_get_contents` or do `echo $doc->saveHTML()`

**Edit**: Didn't realize you had another problem in your code; you can just use this instead:

```
public function _process() {
    return file_get_contents('http://www.oppapers.com/essays/Computerized-World/160871?read_essay');
}
```

Comment: I was trying to get the content of that page. I have edited the original question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error is pretty clear in this case. The _process() method cannot convert from one data type to another, it is expecting String and your feeding it a DomDocument. Perhaps you should try to extract all the text out of the DomDocument first as a string and then send that to the _process() method.

Comment: I was trying to get the content of that page. I have edited the original question.